# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "hacerse el de la vista gorda" o "hacer alguien la vista gorda"?

Tags: coloquialismos, locuciones

En el DLE se explica el significado de la frase:

> [**hacer alguien la vista gorda**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bvx0J4S)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Fingir con disimulo que no ha visto algo.

Y en el DAMER lo menciona también:

> [**hacerse de la vista gorda**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=vista)

Me causa curiosidad lo de "gorda". No es un adjetivo muy natural para aplicarlo a *vista*. ¿Cuál puede ser el origen de la frase?

Comment: Hacerse de la vista gorda es hacerse disimulado o tonto. Antes esa palabra se usaba no con los gordos si no con los perezosos, los poco responsables. Proviene de un lenguaje antiquísimo. El lenguaje es evolutivo como todo y algunas palabras también caen en desuso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ya desde antiguo se tiene la idea de la *granularidad fina* en contraposición a la *granularidad gruesa*: algo basto frente a algo fino. Así, hoy día tenemos la locución latina

> ***[grosso modo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JZm1qAN)***
>
> Loc. lat.; literalmente 'de manera burda'.
>
> 1. loc. adv. A bulto, aproximadamente, más o menos.

que representa precisamente esta idea: algo que no se ha hilado fino se mantiene en un estadio de "grano gordo".

Siguiendo esta idea, podemos ver en el *Diccionario de autoridades* expresiones como:

> Ser de entendimiento *gordo*. Phrase con que se explica tener ingénio bronco, nada perspicáz ni agúdo.
>
> GRUESSO DE INGENIO. Se llama el rudo y tardo en entender y conocer las cosas.

Estas expresiones se ven en el CORDE:

> *La gloria de vuestra fama
>
>   de metros de vuestra boca
>
>   es, par Dios,
>
>   una muy ardiente flama
>
>   que todo el trobar advoca
>
>   en loor de sólo vos;
>
>   con grueso ingenio lo digo,
>
>   reçevid el buen talante,
>
>   que no soy, mi buen amigo,
>
>   para loaros bastante.*
>
> Antón de Montoro, "Cancionero", c1445-1480 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Y d'esta manera en la cámara primera, porque si el seso de aquélla es muy frío, es el hombre qual llamamos atronado y tanto quanto es más frío tiene más gruesso el ingenio y quanto menos lo tiene es el ingenio mejor.*
>
> Alonso de Fuentes, "Suma de Filosofía natural", 1547 (España).

Esta misma idea se trasladaba al siguiente concepto: un hombre de ojos grandes y abiertos se consideraba más bobalicón que uno con ojos pequeños y cerrados. Véase el siguiente texto:

> Capitulo .xxviii. de los ojos.
>   Los ojos grandes & gruessos & muy abiertos: significan ser el hombre perezoso 
>   & algunas vezes osado / inuido: en parte vergonçoso & parte no secreto: habile: auaro / vano: de ligero mintroso: de gran saña: & de mala memoria: de gruesso ingenio: & de poco intellecto: & menos sabio de lo que piensa.
>
> Anónimo, "Tratado médico (Tratado de la patología general)", a1500 (España).

Con todo esto presente, podemos imaginar pues lo que significa "hacer la vista gorda": hacer como que uno tiene los ojos gruesos y por tanto ser de entendimiento gordo.

Comment: Y además, aunque marcada como en desuso, hay una acepción de *gordo* en el DLE que encaja con todo eso perfectamente: *7. adj. desus. Torpe, tonto, poco avisado.*

Comment: @blonfu veo que tienes la vista fina.

Answer (score 6):

Por una parte, la expresión es antigua. Aparece, por ejemplo, en la primera parte del *Guzmán de Alfarache* de Mateo Alemán (1599):

> "... Y debe de ser así, pues el guarda, el malsín, el cuadrillero, el alguacil, todos lo ven y hacen la **vista gorda**, sin que alguno la ofenda.."

aunque no parece haber entrado en el Diccionario de la Lengua hasta 1817.

En cuanto a su origen, y es pura especulación, yo diría que es una contraposición a **afinar la vista** o **aguzar la vista**, que el CORDE recoge desde antes (Fray Bartolomé de las Casas: Apologética historia sumaria 1527-1550):

> "... que para verlos había menester aguzar la vista, tan disimulados estaban ..."

Answer (score 3):

No sé si estoy en lo cierto, pero también algo puedo especular.

La palabra *gordo* viene del latín *gurdus*, que originalmente no tenía que ver con el volumen del cuerpo, sino que significaba "boto", "obtuso", es decir, con las puntas romas o poco afiladas.

Y parece que hay una metáfora habitual en la que se relaciona la forma con la sagacidad: *gordus* también significaba "necio". Del mismo modo, en el diccionario, *boto* significa tanto "romo" como "rudo o torpe de ingenio o de algún sentido". *Embotar* significa "hacer romos los filos" y "enervar, debilitar o hacer menos activo y eficaz algo". *Obtuso* es algo que carece de punta y alguien que tarda en comprender. Al contrario, ser *agudo* significa ser "despierto" o "avispado".

Siguiendo la misma dirección de *boto*, tal vez *gordo* en el pasado también significó "torpe" o "poco efectivo". Y tal vez *hacer la vista gorda* significaba "poner poca atención, tener los sentidos torpes o embotados", o algo similar.

Comment: ¿O sea que *gordo* sería lo contrario de *ágil*?

Comment: @aparente001 Sólo en su etimología. Según veo en el diccionario, ahora significa "corpulento", nada con torpe.

Comment: Generalmente los más agiles son algo delgados.  (Claro que hay excepciones.)

Answer (score -1):

Parece en tu explicación de el vocablo “gordo” olvidaste de la vista como el producto de un trabajo aduanal; así que, siendo “gordo” equivalente a “obtuso” “burdo”, hacer (no hacerse) la vista gorda es hacer una revisión aduanal sin tanto detalle, burdo, obtuso; para no desvelar algún contrabando.